# Library function call is very slow

Tags: c#, dll, garbage-collection

I have a C# application that makes calls to another C# library (dll). The library is added to my C# application under references in Visual Studio. Every time I make a call to the library it takes around 5 seconds to execute the first statement in the function I called. I have no clue why it takes such a long time. My CPU is doing nothing with GBs of free RAM.

Can someone help me out how to debug this issue and find what causing the delay in calling the function?

Edit: After spending some more time on this it came down to the below

### File1.cs

```
using mylib;
void showName()
{
    using(log myLog = new log("abc"))
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

### File2.cs in mylib

```
public class log:IDisposable
{
    public log(string name)  
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

So to call the constructor in the mylib, it is always taking 4 seconds. I replaced "using" with "try...finally" with few log statements and observed that the first log statement in the constructor printed 4 seconds after the call made from File1.cs in "using" statment.

Comment: This is because first call is causing JIT to compile method to native code. To compile method beforehand read about [ngen](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/clrcodegeneration/archive/2010/04/27/ngen-getting-started-with-ngen-in-visual-studio.aspx)

Comment: @gzaxx Op says *Every time I make a call to the library it takes around 5 seconds to execute*. How that's related to JIT?

Comment: What are arguments of the function? Probably serialization / deserialization takes that long.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel The OP also says "5 seconds to execute the **first statement**".

Comment: @Mad Sorcerer: It is the same time irrespective of whether it got function parameter or not.

Comment: @dav_i: The time delay is always there whether you call the same function multiple times or different functions in the same library.

Comment: @dav_i That doesn't matter. **Every time I make a call to the library it takes around 5 seconds**. If JIT is the problem, why would it take 5 seconds everytime?

Comment: What is the application type? Where is the dll at runtime? What are the statements you are invoking? I'm thinking it could be network related or due to some initialisation of the classes involved. A dll is already compiled into CLR, so it wouldn't be JIT compilation.

Comment: My application runs as service. The exe that runs as service and the library that it refers reside in the same directory. The library I'm referring here refers another two libraries.